# Problem with running Ruby with Cron

Tags: ruby, linux, cron

My ruby file is like this.

```
`mkdir #{HOST} -p`
```

It works fine by:  `ruby mycode.rb`

But in a cron job

0 * * * * ruby ~/backup.rb >> backup.log

It will a `-p` folder. Why?

Comment: Um, what does it do when it runs under Cron? 

When it runs under cron, is it running under a different user than when you run it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The #1 problem that anybody runs into with cron jobs is that usually, for security reasons, cron jobs run with a minimal `$PATH`. So, it *could* be that your cron job runs with a different path than when you run the script from the shell, which would mean that it is *possible* that within the cron job a different `mkdir` comman gets called, which interprets its arguments differently.

*Usually*, the first filename argument stops option processing and everything that comes after that will be treated as a filename. So, since `#{HOST}` is a filename, everything after that will *also* be treated as a filename, which means that the call will be interpreted as "make two directories, one named `#{HOST}` and the other named `-p`" If you look for example at the specification of `mkdir`, it is simply illegal to pass an option *after* the filenames.

Another possibility is that for some reason `#{HOST}` will be empty when running under cron. Then the whole call expands to `mkdir -p`, which again, depending on your implementation of `mkdir` *might* be interpreted as "create one directory named `-p`".

It is not quite clear to me why you are passing the options and operands in the wrong order, instead of `mkdir -p #{HOST}`. It's also not clear to me why you use the shell *at all*, instead of just `FileUtils.mkdir_p(HOST)`.

Answer (score 1):

Another problem I've seen is the #! script line fails when /usr/bin/env is used.  For instance:

`#!/usr/bin/env ruby`

doesn't find ruby when running under cron.  You have to use

`#!/usr/local/bin/ruby`

or the equivalent on your platform.